# Leaflet styling geoJSON object radius by its feature property

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I am trying to style geoJSON objects by its feature properties (Capacity). I tried 2 ways:

```
1:

function getWidth(Capacity) {
return Capacity >= 40 ? 12 :
       Capacity >= 30 ? 8 :
       Capacity >= 20 ? 6 :
       Capacity >= 10 ? 3 :
       0;
       }

function getSize(h) {
return h >= 40 ? 12 :
       h >= 30 ? 8 :
       h >= 20 ? 6 :
       h >= 10 ? 3 :
       0;
       }

  function mystyle(feature) {
  if (currentZoom <= 12) {
    return {
      weight: 1, 
      opacity: 0.5,
    };
  }
  else {
    return {
      weight: getWidth(feature.properties.Capacity),
      radius: getSize(feature.properties.Capacity)
    };
  }
}

var johnlewis = L.geoJSON(jl, {
 style: mystyle,
 pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng);
},
  }).addTo(map);
```

and as a result I got something like this:

[image]

where only weight changed, although the zoom level 12 set in function `(map.getZoom()` doesn't work at all.

In my 2nd example:

```
  function style2(feature) {
return {
    fillColor: setColor(feature.properties.Type),
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: '#ffffff',
    dashArray: '3'
};
}   

var johnlewis = L.geoJSON(jl, {
style: function(feature) {
                    if (feature.properties.Capacity >= 5) {
                        return {
                            weight: 1,
                            radius: 4
                        };
                    }
                    if (feature.properties.Capacity >= 10) {
                        return {
                            weight: 2,
                            radius: 6
                        };
                    }
                    if (feature.properties.Capacity >= 20) {
                        return {
                            weight: 3,
                            radius: 8
                        };
                    }
                    else style2
                },

    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng);
    },
  }).addTo(map);
```

It looks slightly better, because the records has been distinguished both by weight and radius, however there is no default situation shown, that was descriubed in the `else` value. Although only 1st `if` responded. Another ones didn't contribute into this view, hence I have only 2 types of radius instead of 4.

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

I want to have a full styled geoJSON by properties, but now I am suffering for a lack of default style.

I saw a few similar examples, but basically they doesn't match my situation.

**EDIT:**

Recently I tried stuff like this:

```
 function mystyle(feature) {
 var rad;
 if (feature.properties.Capacity = 3) {
   rad = 4;
    } else if (feature.properties.Capacity = 5) {
    rad = 6;
    }
    else if (feature.properties.Capacity = 18) {
    rad = 8;
    } else {
    rad = 1;
    }
    return {
    fillColor: '#ff4d4d',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    weight: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    radius: rad,
    color: '#ffffff',
    dashArray: '3'
   };
}   

 var johnlewis = L.geoJSON(jl, {
 style:mystyle,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng);
    },
   }).addTo(map);
```

but instead of the radius I have got changes with the border weight (`weight`).
See the result on the map below:
[image]

So it looks like the radius changes aren't supported in Leaflet are they?

Answer (score 0):

Using L.Circle instead of circleMarker allows you to set the radius as part of the pointToLayer fuction.